# Searching a File in a folder with number pattern

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have given below find command to find and list all the files in a folder, The files are listed in alphabetical order but I want to list all the files in number pattern. when i used "-number" in place of "-name" it is not working.

```
find . -type f -name '*'
I100001093
I200001093
I300001093
XB00001093
I100001094
I200001094
I300001094
XB00001094
I100001095
I200001095
I300001095
XB00001095
```

can anyone please suggest me the right command to list in numerical order.

Answer (score 1):

Depending how you want the `I` and `X` and so forth parts to be handled, you might be able to just use the `sort` command like:

```
find . -type f | sort -n
```

if that isn't the sort order you want, you'll have to give us more detail (and ideally show us the desired output from your example).

Given that you want to group the start of the names together, we can specify the key field to sort.  Since the output from find will start with `./{id}` with the next two characters (seemingly) being related in a batch together, we can start sorting from the 5th character on line specifying the sort key:

```
find . -type f | sort -n -k 1.5
```

`-k` for sort lets you specify the key on which to sort, here we're sorting on the first field, but starting at the 5th character then using `-n` to sort numerically

If you want only the current directory, you can use `-maxdepth` as in:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -n -k 1.5
```

if you want it to be portable:

```
find . -path '*/*/*' -prune -o -type f | sort -n -k 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the quickly reply.
actually here (I100001093, I200001093,I300001093,XB00001093) are one batch files so when ever i give the command then it should list files by batch wise.

Comment: @amarnadhmanikanta Ok, I updated it to hopefully handle that situation

Comment: find . -type f | sort -n -k 1.5

Thanks. This command work in listing batch wise.
i want to list only in present working directory files but here it is listing present and also sub folder as well. do we have any argument to fulfill my requirement. 

i found -l will help but not sure where exactly it should be placed in the command.

Comment: @amarnadhmanikanta there's a `-maxdepth` option to find, so I updated the answer to show that too

Comment: find: 0652-017 -maxdepth is not a valid option.

i am getting that exception.

Comment: @amarnadhmanikanta `-maxdepth` has to be in the correct spot or it won't work, what is either the actual command you ran or the version of `find` you have?

Comment: find -v ====> Usage: find [-H | -L] Path-list [Expression-list].........i ran the same command "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -n -k 1.5" in my server.

Comment: @amarnadhmanikanta what system are you on?

Comment: @amarnadhmanikanta ok, I have a POSIX version that should work for you now--I hope